# Is it better to ask for the password a user wants after e-mail verification or before in a system where accounts are based on e-mail address?

Tags: validation, email, architecture, verification

In our system,

before a user gets to create an account based on e-mail address, we ask him/her to validate possession of this address by sending a mail containing a link containing a token which is to be clicked.

I see a lot of similar systems asking for the password the user wants to use to log in BEFORE the e-mail address is verified (in the first input form). So that once the user clicks the link and the server creates the user, the user can use that password to log in.

Alternatively, I see a lot of systems asking for a wanted password AFTER the user clicked the link. However, I get the feeling this is used less.

My question: which method/process is superior (safety over user experience) and why?

I personally can see at least 1 con for the first method, as a potentially malicious non-owner may request to create an account based on someone else's e-mail address. Then, if somehow the legitimate user of that e-mail address clicks the verification link, as many would do without thinking, the address is verified and the password that the non-owner provided is used.

So, I am thinking to use the method of asking the user to provide a password AFTER e-mail address verification. However, I am curious if there are other problems that come with option two. And why you think which of the two is best. Or maybe an alternative to both, who knows.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I am suggesting a alternative, why? Because in both the methods a malicious user or if your system had the wrong email address in the first place, can set the password. I would say use standard multi factor authentication here. To keep it simple you can use 2 factor authentication one factor being the email and the other factor being some other piece or information  that only your system and the user knows. This could be a pin or date of birth (dob is not so secretive) or some other piece of data.  A very well founded way of applying 2 factor authentication is to send a PIN number via SMS on users pre recorded mobile number. For more details google 2 factor authentication or multi factor authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will look into them. However, I didn't understand why in the second method I mentioned the malicious user can set the password.

Comment: @GlobalRationality imagine if your system records had the wrong email address for the user , you would have sent the email to someone who can click the link and set the password. And please no need for thanks if the answer help please mark it as chosen answers.